# How to make out.println() method working in a simple java file without using System Class reference?

Tags: import, static

public class ABC{  public static void main(String[] args)  {  out.println("Hello");  }  }

Answer (score 0):

This works, though static imports are not generally considered a good thing in java.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You ,For resolving the query